# Remove an element from nested lists with mixed structures (lists and integers) in Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

Consider the lists:

```
assigned = [4,8]
matching = [['B', [4, 5, 6]], ['C', [7, 8, 9]]]
```

I am trying to remove given integers with the following code

```
for ii in range(len(assigned)):
    while any(assigned[ii] in x for x in matching):
        matching.remove(assigned[ii])
```

I have two problems here.
First one is to get into the inner lists.
Right now the code does nothing because there is no matching.

Second problem, I tried this:

```
t = ['B', [4, 5, 6]]
if any(4 in x for x in l2):
```

And the result was an error:

```
if any(4 in x for x in l2):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Is there any way to achieve both in no more than two lines of code: found matching in nested lists and remove those matchings?

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary `dict(matching)` for that? Might be easier to work with.

Comment: Do you care about the order of elements?

Comment: I prefer to keep lists structures, because of the rest of the code I am handling. And the order doesn't matter, I just want to get rid off the elements.

Comment: Have you tried `if any(4 in [x for x in l2]):`? It will generate a list due to list comprehension in every loop though.

Comment: @emremrah Have you tried it?  if any(4 in [x for x in l2]):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach with list comprehension if you prefer to use `.remove()`

```py
assigned = [4,8]
matching = [['B', [4, 5, 6]], ['C', [7, 8, 9]]]
[item[1].remove(x) for item in matching for x in item[1] if x in assigned]
print(matching)
# [['B', [5, 6]], ['C', [7, 9]]]
```

Above is basically a list comprehension version of:

```py
for item in matching:
    for x in item[1]:
        if x in assigned:
            item[1].remove(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using a nested list comprehension:

```py
matching = [[i[0], [j for j in i[1] if j not in assigned]] for i in matching]
print(matching)
```

Output:

```
[['B', [5, 6]], ['C', [7, 9]]]
```